# Uncaught Invariant Violation : invalid react child

Tags: reactjs

While clicking the button it takes me to an empty page . Then i check console so i find out .

I have tried everything to fix this.

```js
addOption = (e) => {
        this.setState({options: [...this.state.options,
            {[e.target.previousSibling.value] : 0}]})
}
render(){
        const optionals = this.state.options.map(option=>{
            return(
                <li key={option}>{option}</li>
            )
        })
        const topics = this.state.topics.map(topic =>{
            return(
                <span onClick={this.selectTopic} key={topic}>{topic}</span>
            )
        })
```

> **Uncaught Invariant Violation**: Objects are not valid as a React child
>   (found: object with keys {asdf}). If you meant to render a collection
>   of children, use an array instead.

Comment: Please post your react component snippet (atleast the render) in proper formatted manner so that its readable.

Comment: Please show your render method, it's impossible to tell what your issue is otherwise.

Comment: The problem here comes from another place (mostly `render()` method) and you have to provide more of your component to find the issue.